# Blank page displaying in telerik reporting

Tags: telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I have one master page and inheriting the master page in my detail page. For report we are using Telerik Reporting Controls. After bind the report we are getting extra blank pages.

Can you guide me fow the reason for this

Comment: please can you confirm what format you are exporting to, im having similar problems with exporting to RTF : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886296/telerik-report-multiple-blank-pages-when-using-rtf-against-pdf

Answer (score 2):

Use a iframe and set the source of u r iframe to the report page. To bind the report you have to first set the source of report viewer to your report an include that page in iframe of master page. You cannot directly view the report on master page. Use telerik report viewer and set its source to your report.